# Inheritance: Are parent objects created each time I call 'super'?

Tags: python

consider the following code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('class A is being constructed')

    def print_msg(self):
        print('Hello, I am class A')

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print('class B is being constructed')

    def print_msg(self):
        super(B, self).print_msg()
        print('Hello, I am class B')
```

As you can see, I call `super(B, self)` each time `B.print_msg()` is called.

My question is whether each time I do it, it constructs a new object of A, or is it an object that was initially created and I just get its reference each time?

In other words, would the following code construct A 100 times?

```
b = B()
for i in range(100):
    b.print_msg()
```

The reason I got into wondering about it, is that the parent's `.__init__()` method is not automatically called when the child's object is created.

Comment: What is printed when you run the code?

Comment: @JimWright It prints A's message followed by B's message a hundred times

Comment: No, when you use `super()` you're just referring to an existing **class** object.

Comment: @JimWright and before it, it prints once A's c'tor message followed by B's c'tor message

Comment: Parent objects are not. A *proxy* object, however, is.

Comment: @Chur7U You've answered your own question. The constructor is only ran when an object is created.

Comment: @JimWright it is a bit tricky, as if I don't call the parent's `.__init__()` explicitly, it is not executed. So how can I be sure the parent object is really existing before I first call `super()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super` is not a function; it is actually a *class* whose instances encapsulate knowledge about the method resolution order of the classes involved.

`super(B, self)` returns an instance (a proxy object) that knows the MRO for whatever type `self` has, as well as the fact that you want to skip the classes in the MRO between `self.__class__` and `B`. When you invoke a method on the proxy, it finds the correct method to call, then passes `self` as an argument to that method.

Let's say the object `self` was an instance of a class `A` whose MRO looked like `[A, C1, C2, C3, C4, B, C5, C6]`. Normally, a call to `A.foo()` would check if `A` had a method `foo`, and if not, proceed to check `C1`, `C2`, etc, in order until it found a class with a method `foo`. `super(B, self)` returns a proxy that basically says, "use an MRO of `[B, C5, C6]`" so that when you write `super(B, self).foo()`, Python skips right to `B` if `A.foo` doesn't exist.

In the vast majority of cases, `super` is used to just skip the instance's class itself, trimming one class off the front of the MRO. This is the behavior that Python 3 makes simple by letting you omit the arguments to `super`.

Answer (score 1):

No, the code below will construct an A exactly once:

```
b = B()
for i in range(100):
    b.print_msg()
```

This would happen implicitly in the line `b = B()`, because B is an A.

The object `super(B, self)` is a *proxy*.  It will use the class object `A`, however it doesn't need to actually create an *instance* of `A`.